# How to oxidize tantalum?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, redox, applied-chemistry

I am interested in learning how to oxidize tantalum. I have seen some tantalum rings that the sellers say is a permanent smokey blackish color. But I've spoken to some people that say tantalum cannot be oxidized, and the rings I saw must have been coated.

So anyone know if and how tantalum can be oxidized?

Comment: Any metal can be oxidized. Although Ta is rather resistant, there's lots of ways. As for the black color, it might be [tantalum nitride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tantalum_nitride), but this question falls under both unclear and too broad, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

The smoky black stuff is probably not tantalum oxide.  The only such oxide that's well characterized is $\ce{Ta2O5}$, which is [white](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tantalum_pentoxide).  Tantalum itself is a rare element, so if the jewelry contains tantalum at all it's probably a thin coating or cladding on a base metal substrate.